# Replace visual studio 2012 Diff tool with winmerge when using Microsoft Git Provider

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, version-control, git-extensions, winmerge

I have a Visual Studio 2012 v3 and git extensions installed.

I want to change the default merge tool to winmerge but it seems that this is not a trivial task when Microsoft Git Provider is chosen.

When i go to VS -> Tools -> Options -> Source Control I have only Plug-in-Selection tab and cannot choose configure tools to change to WinMerge.

[image: Screenshot]

Is there any way of using Git Extensions with WinMerge inside VS2012?

Comment: Note also that Git Extensions are not the Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Git, they are two different technologies.

Answer (score 14):

Backed up by that [DZone-article](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/how-configure-diff-and-merge), the trick is to configure the diff-tool in git.config:

1. Open the git bash in your repository
2. Create a config section for WinMerge as a diff-tool:

   ```
   $ git config --local difftool.winmerge.cmd '"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"'
   ```
3. Configure git to switch to WinMerge as the diff-tool:

   ```
   $ git config --local diff.tool winmerge
   ```

If you want to have this setting as a global setting, replace the `--local` switch with `--global`.

Comment: I think you mean replace `--local` with `--global`.

Comment: @TheMouthofaCow Thank you for the hint - you're right of course. Edited my response accordingly.

Comment: It works for kdiff3 as well. Just replace winmerge with kdiff3.

Comment: What is "difftool.winmerge.cmd"? Is it a file from winmerge?